# How to open next folder in working directory for only one file?

Tags: r, read.csv, setwd

I have a working directory

```
setwd("C:/User/WorkDirectory")
```

I have files in the working directory

```
"File 1.csv", "File 2.csv", "File 3.csv", "Folder 1"
```

I have no problem accessing the 3 files

```
df1<-read.csv("File 1.csv",check.names=FALSE)
```

However i would like to open the file in the folder `Folder 1` while maintaining my working directory as it is.

I tried something like this

```
read.csv(paste0(setwd("./Folder 1/"),"File Another 1.csv"))
```

Is there a nice and elegant way of doing this. There is a reason I'm trying to do this as this folder contains a sub section of files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `file.path` - `setwd` is for setting the directory, whereas `getwd` returns the path of working directory.

```
setwd("C:/User/WorkDirectory")
read.csv(file.path(getwd(), "Folder 1", "Another 1.csv"))
```

Or we may also use `.` to signify the working directory

```
read.csv(file.path(".", "Folder 1", "Another 1.csv"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not completely clear on your intent, but I guess a recursive `list.files` can be helpful here;

```
setwd("C:/User/WorkDirectory")
temp <- list.files(pattern = "*.csv", recursive = T)
```

This lists the CSV files within `WorkDirectory` and its sub-folders. You can loop through the listed files and read them into your environment;

```
my_csv_files <- lapply(temp, read.csv)
```

or if you want them as multiple dataframes saved to your environment and not as a list of dataframes like above:

```
list2env(
  lapply(setNames(temp, make.names(gsub(".*/([^.]+).*", "\\1", temp))), 
         read.csv), envir = .GlobalEnv)
```